# grep -f and A2 combined and partial matches

Tags: string, awk, grep

I want to do a `grep -f` match from `fileA` onto `fileB`. I want to extract the matched line and the two lines that follow the matched line. Sometimes the match is only partial like `mmu-let-7f` matching `mmu-let-7f-1`.

I have been trying `grep -f and grep -A2`, but I don't know how to combine them.

fileA

```
mmu-mir-125b-1
mmu-mir-30c
mmu-mir-96
mmu-let-7f
...
```

fileB

```
>mmu-let-7f-1 MI0000562 Mus musculus let-7f-1 stem-loop
ATCAGAGTGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAGTTGTGGGGTAGTGATTTTACCCTGTTTAGGAGA
TAACTATACAATCTATTGCCTTCCCTGAG
>mmu-let-7f-2 MI0000563 Mus musculus let-7f-2 stem-loop
TGTGGGATGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAGTTTTAGGGTCATACCCCATCTTGGAGATAACTA
TACAGTCTACTGTCTTTCCCACG
>mmu-mir-15a MI0000564 Mus musculus miR-15a stem-loop
CCCTTGGAGTAAAGTAGCAGCACATAATGGTTTGTGGATGTTGAAAAGGTGCAGGCCATA
CTGTGCTGCCTCAAAATACAAGGA
....
```

Comment: What is wrong with `grep -A2 -f fileA fileB`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You just need to make sure that you have a space character at the end of each line in the patterns file.

fileA

```
mmu-mir-125b-1 
mmu-mir-30c 
mmu-mir-96 
mmu-let-7f
```

fileB

```
>mmu-let-7f-1 MI0000562 Mus musculus let-7f-1 stem-loop
ATCAGAGTGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAGTTGTGGGGTAGTGATTTTACCCTGTTTAGGAGA
TAACTATACAATCTATTGCCTTCCCTGAG
>mmu-let-7f-2 MI0000563 Mus musculus let-7f-2 stem-loop
TGTGGGATGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAGTTTTAGGGTCATACCCCATCTTGGAGATAACTA
TACAGTCTACTGTCTTTCCCACG
>mmu-mir-15a MI0000564 Mus musculus miR-15a stem-loop
CCCTTGGAGTAAAGTAGCAGCACATAATGGTTTGTGGATGTTGAAAAGGTGCAGGCCATA
CTGTGCTGCCTCAAAATACAAGGA
>mmu-let-7f MI0000562 Mus musculus let-7f stem-loop
test
```

In this case the `grep -A2 -f fileA fileB` will work.

```
$ grep -A2 -f  fileA fileB
>mmu-let-7f MI0000562 Mus musculus let-7f stem-loop
test
```

Comment: this wont work for multiple matches fgrep is better. It is explicitly used for files.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
fgrep -f fileA fileB -A2
```

this should work for what you are trying to do.

Output in your case:

```
>mmu-let-7f-1 MI0000562 Mus musculus let-7f-1 stem-loop
ATCAGAGTGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAGTTGTGGGGTAGTGATTTTACCCTGTTTAGGAGA
TAACTATACAATCTATTGCCTTCCCTGAG
>mmu-let-7f-2 MI0000563 Mus musculus let-7f-2 stem-loop
TGTGGGATGAGGTAGTAGATTGTATAGTTTTAGGGTCATACCCCATCTTGGAGATAACTA
TACAGTCTACTGTCTTTCCCACG
```